# Remove specific repeating string (but leaving one behind)

Tags: javascript

```
var oldString = "Test---NEWLINE------NEWLINE---This is another line.---NEWLINE---And another line.---NEWLINE------NEWLINE------NEWLINE---One more line.";
```

I only want one "---NEWLINE---" to appear at a time.  If there are multiple next to each other, I want them removed.  So the new string would be:

```
var newString = "Test---NEWLINE---This is another line.---NEWLINE---And another line.---NEWLINE---One more line.";
```

Comment: Let's see what you tried first and your effort right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace is a good choice:

```
var newString = oldString.replace(/(---NEWLINE---){2,}/g, '---NEWLINE---');
```

But only multiple "---NEWLINE---".

Answer (score 1):

Thor has one solution, here's another dumb one that handles any amount of ---NEWLINE--- occurrences together:

```
var oldString = "Test---NEWLINE------NEWLINE---This is another line.---NEWLINE---And another line.---NEWLINE------NEWLINE------NEWLINE---One more line.";

var split = oldString.split('---NEWLINE---');
var newSplit = [];
for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    if (split[i].length != 0) {
        newSplit.push(split[i]);
    }
}

var newString = newSplit.join('---NEWLINE---');
```

Answer (score 0):

real stupid way:

```
replace("---NEWLINE------NEWLINE---", "---NEWLINE---").replace("---NEWLINE------NEWLINE---", "---NEWLINE---")
```

first one will still leave one double left, second will sort that out.

Answer (score 0):

probably something like the following, assuming you split on spaces.

```
var stringParse = oldString.split(" ");
var count = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < stringParse.length; i++){
    if (count == 0 && stringParse[i] == '---NEWLINE---'){
        count ++;
    } else if (count > 0 && stringParse[i] == '---NEWLINE---'){
        stringParse[i] = "";
    }
}
var newString = stringParse.join(" ");
```

I assumed that by NEWLINE you meant \n, and that the hyphens were you omitting text rather than literal hyphens.

Comment: Hmm, lemme check again. Thought I had why but my first guess was wring.

Comment: well like I said in the post, I was assuming NEWLINE was referring to the newline character. If that's not the case he can replace \n with whatever the actual string is.

Comment: Seeing as the author likely hasn't tried anything themselves, they should get on it...

Comment: ---NEWLINE--- is a mnemonic, not a \n or carriage return.  I will eventually be treating it like that, but for now I need it to stay ---NEWLINE---

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string into an array by newline, remove empty array elements, and rejoin it.

```
var str = "Test---NEWLINE------NEWLINE---This is another line.---NEWLINE---And another line.---NEWLINE------NEWLINE------NEWLINE---One more line.";

var newStr = str.split("---NEWLINE---").filter(function (el) { 
  return el.length;
}).join("---NEWLINE---");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (oldstring.Contains("---NEWLINE------NEWLINE---"))
{
    oldstring.Replace("---NEWLINE------NEWLINE---","---NEWLINE---");
}
```